# Why is `df -h` not showing the whole disk space?

Tags: hard-drive, disk, disk-usage

I recently formatted my hdd to increase the partition size for Ubuntu. Despite the actual 170 GB free space (sda5), Ubuntu shows only 27 GB when prompted via properties. Here is my `df-h` output:

```
alper@ubuntu:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop0       29G  3.1G   26G  11% /
udev            956M  4.0K  956M   1% /dev
tmpfs           386M  884K  385M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            965M   80K  965M   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda5       173G  5.0G  169G   3% /host
/dev/sdb1       932G  439G  493G  48% /media/Alper
/dev/sda4       173G   66G  107G  39% /media/Storage
/dev/sda2       120G   85G   36G  71% /media/Windows 7
```

Gparted also shows the correct space values, but when I right click on home or file system, it shows 27 GB and does not let me copy necessary files (about 100 GB total). I tried previous "missing disk space" solutions around here but couldn't fix the problem. Hope someone can help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your root filesystem ``/`` (including ``/home``) is the ``/dev/loop0`` device. Please clarify that part, as that is not on a regular hard drive partition. Resizing partitions won't help you out.

Comment: Yes, I guess that's the problem (I'm pretty new to UNIX, so I don't have much idea about what I'm doing). I'm still searching the problem on older threads and seen that wubi windows installer is the problem. I tried to install Ubuntu with disc, but it couldn't proceed because of a missing file so I tried to install it with wubi. How can I install it properly on selected partition?

Comment: Ah Wubi. Hmm. You could try to relocate your ``/home`` to a separate partition. This is not going to be really easy if you are not familiar with Linux/UNIX. Here's a guide, but I'm not sure if it's targeted to Wubi installations as well. [Partitioning/Home/Moving](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving)

Comment: @user90965 Here's a question that tells you how to install Ubuntu - [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When installed using wubi (the Windows installer) the file system is limited to 30GB max, no matter what the target partition is. If you want to use more space, in fact, if you plan on using Ubuntu for anything other then testing, do a proper installation.

Comment: True to recommend a proper installation. However, I think relocating the ``/home`` partition could help too (see my comment on the question).

Comment: Thanks, I think I have to make disc install happen then. I need that much free space for the task.

Comment: Can you relocate home from a wubi installation? I've never tried that.